# Is there any point in specifying the precision and scale of a number for a foreign key?

Tags: oracle, foreign-key, datatypes, data-integrity

I am running Oracle 11gR2 11.2.0.3. I have two tables:

- `table1` contains a column named `SUBJECT_ID`, whose datatype is `NUMBER(7,0)` (numbers range from 13 to 48480)
- `table2` contains a a column named `SUBJECT_ID`, whose datatype is `NUMBER`, and is a foreign key to `table1.SUBJECT_ID`.

Is there any point in specifying the precision and scale of `table1.SUBJECT_ID` (i.e. declaring it `NUMBER(7,0)` instead of simply `NUMBER`)?

The [Oracle documentation advises](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1832) to specify the precision and scale, as "it provides extra integrity checking on input". But in my case wouldn't the foreign key constraint take care of this integrity checking?

Comment: *why* are you wondering?  Is there something you're not mentioning?

Comment: @MaxVernon Just wondering if I haven't missed anything in my reasoning. In there is no point in specifying the precision and scale of a number for a foreign key, then I won't invest my time in making sure the schema contains `NUMBER` instead of ` NUMBER(7,0)`.

Comment: It is always best to be explicit.  In future, looking at the column definition will leave no doubt if you declare it as the type it actually is.

Comment: @MaxVernon Thanks, I agree for explicitness. Do you see any other motivation to specify the precision and scale in this case?

Comment: Computer programers and DBAs ought to be anal about consistency. I know I am. Make both sides identical in terms of datatypes, nullability (assuming a mandatory foreign key), name (where possible) and no one can wonder if there wasn't some slip-up. I'd add a comment on the column if the foreign key is optional.

Comment: For example it might help someone to deduce whether integers or floats are stored in it.

Answer (score 2):

Connor MacDonald blogged about this over in [NUMBER data type... what harm can it do?](https://connormcdonald.wordpress.com/2015/04/20/number-data-type-what-harm-can-it-do/) as well as [Ask Tom: "How do I determine how much storage will be required for NUMBER(p, s)?"](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1856720300346322149). In short, it does matter.

Take this table:

```
CREATE TABLE T ( 
    x1 number,
    x2 number(6,3)
);
```

`x1` will be 21 bytes while `x2` will be 2 bytes. By not specifying the data type, you're taking up extra space that may not be needed.

Comment: `number` is a variable length data type. So `x1` will take **up to** 21 bytes. If you store the number 42, it will take exactly the same space in `x1` and `x1`

Comment: You might want to hit up Connor's link and repro it yourself.

Comment: I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name. The linked page has as example the value of the expression `3*(1/3)` which results (for some unknown reason due to the implementation) to different values, `1.000` or `1.0000....000`, depending on the precision of the column: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f68a4/1

Comment: And I might be wrong about the `1.00000...0000` : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f68a4/13

Comment: I did read the the link and I'm surprised. It apparently has something to do how an expression is evaluated. Just wanted to add that a `number` column does not have a fixed size - similar to the way e.g. a `varchar` works.